# Direct3D Win32 Game Template not Showing up in VS 2019

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, directxtk

I am trying to use the directx TK with visual studio. In the [wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/The-basic-game-loop), it shows the template option "Direct3D Win32 Game"; however, that is not available in my templates. I think that I have installed all of the required work loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Direct3D Win32 Game** is not part of Visual Studio. The Visual Studio UWP workload it does include "DirectX 11 Game" for UWP.

You get "Direct3D WIn32 Game" by installing the VSIX from [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates). There are install links [here](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/releases).